# I am getting this error while sorting 0,1 and 2 in array - Runtime Error Time Limit Exceeded Your program took more time than expected

Tags: c++, sorting

```
class Solution
{
    public:
    void sort012(int a[], int n)
    {
        // code here 
    int low = 0;
    int high = n-1;
    int mid = 0;
        
        while(mid<high)
        
        { 
              int high = n-1;
            if(a[mid]==0 && mid<=high)
           { swap(a[mid++],a[low++]);
         
           }
           else if(a[mid]==2 && mid<=high)
           { swap(a[mid],a[high--]);
           }
           else if(a[mid]==1 && mid<=high)
           {
               mid++;
           }
        }
        
    }
    
};
```

Comment: It is because some part of your algorithm is inefficient. Finding a slick way to solve the problem, is ... what the coding sites are all about. They are not student exercises.

Comment: Duplicate variable `high` with the one within the loop hiding the outer one. `high--` remains without any visible effect as just modifying the inner one while not being read afterwards any more.

Comment: Well they are student excercises in problem solving. They are not excercises to learn good C++, the actual solutions shown on the site are usually of horrendous code quality. And C++ has sort out of the box

Comment: Is the array appropriately initialised at all?

Comment: Have you considered that your program goes into an infinite loop?

Comment: The whole point of this is to get you to understand: You can look through the array, count the number of 0s, the number of 1s and the number of 2s. Then write that many 0s, this many 1s and the rest of 2s.

Comment: The time limit for this problem is probably such that `std::sort(a, a + n);` will time out for at least one input, so you'd have to do what @Jeffrey suggests with as little overhead as possible

Answer (score 1):

Problem number one is you are redefining the `int high = n - 1` inside of the while loop, at each iteration it's reset to this value, so `high--` has no effect, and you're getting inside an infinite loop.

Problem number two is that potentially if you pass an array `a` which has a single value that is not a `0`, `1` or `2`, you are 100% getting into an infinite loop as well.

Check out this compiler explorer link for an interactive demo: https://godbolt.org/z/EbKPqrxz4

---

For what it's worth, you program looks like bad C instead of being C++. Non exhaustive list of issues:

- The sort012 is an instance method on a class while it doesn't use the instance state. It's probably better as a free function, or at worse a static method on that class.
- You're using C arrays.
- As a result, you're also not using the algorithms provided by the STL.

I'm assuming this is a kind of coding exercise, but anyways, for the sake of completeness you could achieve the same thing (and more, it'd work with several containers, and regardless of your values/types) with fewer lines of code with this ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zb5Phxebj)):

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main() {
  std::array<int, 10> a{1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2};
  // Could also be a vector: `std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2};`
  std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  fmt::print("sorted a=");
  for (auto x: a) {
    fmt::print("{}, ", x);
  }
}
```